# Unstable connection to remote server in Docker

Tags: python, docker, ssh

I have created a docker container to run my python program inside.

My program requires retrieving the **known_host** under my .ssh folder:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
```

I have mounted it into the docker container using:

```
docker run --name test_cntr --rm  \
-v $SCRIPT_DIR:/home/ \
-v $DATA_DIR:/home/data \
-v $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts:/root/.ssh/known_hosts \
-e PYTHONPATH=/home/sciprt_dir:/home/sciprt_dir/lib \
-e INDEX=0 \
dummy_image python /home/run.py
```

Found that my program can successfully get the known_hosts file sometimes, but sometimes not, below error is shown:

> Exception is [Errno -2] Name or service not known

I didn't re-run the container during the run.py execution. Suppose the known_hosts mounted to the container at the beginning and run.py should be able to use it throughout whole running.

Comment: Are you sure the `known_hosts` file contains the known host when it fails?

Comment: @tripleee Yes the known_hosts once mounted into the docker container, it won't be amended during whole execution.

Comment: What I mean is if it doesn't already contain the key of the host you are connecting to, that would trivially explain the error completely.

Comment: @tripleee Got what you mean, but currently the behaviour is like, 1st 2nd time ssh successfully, 3rd time failed, 4th 5th success. If it doesn't contain the key of host, suppose it will be failed at the very beginning.

Comment: Depends on whether `server` is the same value each time.

Comment: server is same value each time.

Comment: You should probably [edit] your question to mention this, as well as the failure pattern in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I found that, one of the servers using for this program, did not register on the domain server, so that sometimes my program works when using server that is registered, and sometimes it does not work when the server is not registered.. Thanks all for help!